# Struggling to create a Line graph using R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently attempting to plot a line graph of this data using R studio, but am coming across a load of problems and errors, and just wondered if anyone had an idea where I am going wrong? Thanks so much

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(FINALDATA, aes(x = JAF, 
                      y = Read_Depth, 
                      linetype = Power, 
                      colour = Power, 
                      shape = Power)) +
geom_line(lwd = 1.5) + 
geom_point(size = 4) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "longdash")) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF0000", "#0000FF")) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 17))
```

Again, thanks for any help

Comment: ggplot2 is part of tidyverse so there would be no need to install that separately fyi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help to show us some ot all of `FINALDATA` in a plain-text format using _e.g._ `dput(FINALDATA)`, and also to include the error messages that you are seeing.